# npm install -g -production windows-build-tools is taking too long

Tags: windows, npm, ethereum, truffle

I want to install truffle on my windows machine, so I'm running `npm install -g -production windows-build-tools`  as per [truffle suite guide](https://trufflesuite.com/guides/how-to-install-truffle-and-testrpc-on-windows-for-blockchain-development/#step-2-install-the-tools-via-npm) but it is taking too long.

[powershell screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lur8w.png)

What should I do?